# java - Android Studio build.gradle: Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:8

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have never used Android Studio before so I just wanted to first play around with it but because of this issue, I can't.

I've looked at the other Stackoverflow answers on the other posts but none of them help or they're very very confusing.

> build.gradle: Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:8

That message above is what i get when I try to sync project with gradle files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is there is no dependency like thus:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:8'
```

Change it to

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
```

And sync the files.